# Silverlight App inside WPF WebBrowser?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, wpf-controls

I have a hopefully trivial question.  Currently, my company works with a rather obscure language (SyngergyDE) and we need to call a SilverLight application inside our product.  Unfortunately, this obscure 3rd party language only (currently) supports the opening of WPF screens.  So with that said, I thought I'd develop a small WPF user control that contains a "WebBrowser" control and navigate to the silverlight application's URI.  This works fine, and I'm able to see the SL application.  Here is my question - we have a "Close" button on the SL application, and when users "Click" that button, we want the window to close.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how we can communicate the "Closing of the SL App" to the WPF user control, so that the entire WPF user control closes as well?

Thanks everyone,

-Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach an event handler to the `WebBrowser.Navigated` event.

Have the close button  in the Silverlight application use:-

```
 HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri("about:blank", UriKind.Absolute));
```

When the Navigated event fires in WPF with the url "about:blank" then its time to close the control.

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript and the HTML DOM as the glue here.

For example, when the SL app close button is clicked, have Silverlight trigger some Javascript code that sets a flag, or alternately, raises some HTML document event.

The WPF control could poll that flag in the HTML + Javascript, or alternately listen for that HTML document event, then close the user control.

Comment: How would one go about listening for the html document close event?  I'm able to close the WebBrowser control via javascript (but the User Control remains open), but I'm not sure how to "plug in" a listener to the control (WPF<-WebBrowser)? My apologies if this is a dumb question.