# Embedded Silverlight app inside .NET desktop app and communication between them

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight, interop

I have a WPF app. I need to embed a Silverlight app inside it. As I understand the most common way to do this is using of System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser control (note: my app is wpf not WinForms).
BTW: there's another way to host a Silverlight app - to use its COM interface (see http://www.codeproject.com/KB/atl/Host_Silverlight_In_ATL.aspx).

So in my WPF app I have a WebBrowser somewhere:

```
<WebBrowser x:Name="webBrowser">
```

where I load my html page (let's assume local htlm page for the sake of simplicity):

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser.LoadCompleted += WebBrowser_LoadCompleted;
        webBrowser.Navigate(new Uri(Path.GetFullPath("HostPage.htm")));
    }

    private void WebBrowser_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Silverlight app has loaded");
    }
```

Ok. That's easy.
Now I want to communicate with the host from the SL-app and with the SL-app from the host.

I understand technics for interoperability between HTML(JS) and Silverlight ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645076%28VS.95%29.aspx ) and between .NET and JS inside WebBrowser.
I can set up WebBrowser.ObjectForScripting with an object (marked with ComVisibleAttribute) and the object will be accessing in JS.
I even can get reference to this object from my embedded Silverlight app:

```
(ScriptObject) HtmlPage.Window.GetProperty("external");
```

I also can make some object inside the Silverlight app visible to JS (and probably to host code) via HtmlPage.RegisterScriptableObject("name", anObject);

But. The problem is that in all cases I have to deal with some untyped ScriptObject instances.
But I'd like to set up "fully managed code" communication between the host and the SL-app. I mean passing complex structures/classes/delegates, raising event, and so on, i.e. without any "untyped JS-stuff".

How can I do that?

**UPDATE**:
ok, it seems that there's no nice way to do what I want.
So I have to deal with JS-interoperability. But here I have a problem.
From the host I set up ObjectForScripting and SL-app can use it. That means the SL-app gets results from methods of the object set up in WebBrowser.ObjectForScripting:

```
((ScriptObject) HtmlPage.Window.GetProperty("external")).Invoke("methodName")
```

But not on the contrary.
In my SL-app I register an object (of type BridgeSl):

```
m_bridgeSl = new BridgeSl();
HtmlPage.RegisterScriptableObject("bridge", m_bridgeSl);
```

Then create JS-function in html :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var g_bridgeSl = null;
function pluginLoaded(sender, args) {
    g_bridgeSl = sender.getHost().Content.bridge;
}
</script>
```

where pluginLoaded is handler of the SL plugin's onLoad event:

```
<object id="slCtrl" data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" ...>
  <param name="onLoad" value="pluginLoaded" />
</object>
```

Then add function returning this object:

```
function getBridge() {
  return g_bridgeSl;
}
```

I did all this stuff as I hoped that I can get BridgeSl's instance inside my host app:

```
var bridgeSl = WebBrowser.InvokeScript("getBridge");
```

Actually I get something. It's an instance of "System.__ComObject". But when I cast it to dynamic:

```
dynamic dynBridgeSl = bridgeSl;
```

I get System.SystemException object with message "The method or operation is not implemented". Ok, it's can't be treated as a dynamic, but what is it then? How to invoke any method on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no managed-only interop at this time.  The two options you mention (JavaScript interop over the DOM bridge, or COM hosting) are all that exists.

I do commend you for doing your research - you knew everything I was going to say when I clicked on the question!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure how you'd go about passing complex structures between your SL app and the host, but one option you may have in raising events is passing information via the URL.  Attach an event handler to the `WebBroswer.Navigated` event and have that handler raise your host's event based on the information in the url.

For example, we have a Silverlight application that's hosted inside a WPF WebBrowser control.  We wanted to know when the user clicked the "Close" button inside the Silverlight app.  We attached an event handler to the `WebBrowser.Navigated` and parsed the URL.  We specifically looked for "closed=true" inside that url.  If found, close the entire app (WPF host included).

[Silverlight App inside WPF WebBrowser ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215850/silverlight-app-inside-wpf-webbrowser)

Comment: thanks, that's nice but I need to communication between the host and the SL-app all over the time.